# python twitter OAUTH name 'OAuth' is not defined

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I just learned python, and to use twitter api in book web scraping with python.
I run this program and it didn't work, should I import OAUTH? or what should I do to make it right?

```
from twitter import Twitter

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth('xxx@xx.com', 'xxx', 'xxx','xxx'))
pt = t.search.tweets(q='#python')
print(pt)
```

This question seems a little dumb, but it confused me for hours.

Comment: If you don't import OAuth, then how do you expect it to be defined in the program?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing both `OAuth` and `Twitter` ?

```
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth('xxx@xx.com', 'xxx', 'xxx','xxx'))
pt = t.search.tweets(q='#python')
print(pt)
```